# Variable Not Accessible Travis CI

Tags: github, environment-variables, travis-ci

To put it simply, this works:

```
branches:
  only:
  - master

before_install:
  - sudo apt-get update

install:
  - sudo apt-get install lua5.2

script:
  - lua ./tests/runall_tests.lua
```

but this doesn't:

```
branches:
  only:
  - master

# Running builds in parallel for lua 5.2 and 5.3
env:
  - LUA=lua5.2
  - LUA=lua5.3

before_install:
  - sudo apt-get update

install:
  - sudo apt-get install $LUA

script:
  - lua ./tests/runall_tests.lua
```

The goal of the second version is to be able to run the same job as in the first but for 2 different versions of lua. For some reason I cannot get this to work. The error I get is something like:

```
E: Unable to locate package lua5.3
The command "sudo apt-get install $LUA" failed and exited with 100 during .
```

Comment: Do you see any line like `export LUA=5.2` in the log?

Comment: Also, you are trying to install `5.2` or `5.3` and not something like `LUA5.2`

Comment: You're right I meant `LUA=lua5.2`. Which works for lua 5.2 but not 5.3. It turns out that somehow I can't install that package from the travis build environment. There's probably some way around it, but I have had no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

The package `lua5.3` is not found by `apt-get` in your system.

You could compile it by hand following [this example on github by moteus](https://github.com/moteus/lua-travis-example)